# how to get a cross Joins in Fetch XML queries in CRM2011?

Tags: sql, xml, crm, fetch

> 1.-First Time I do Queries as it then I dont know how to get a cross join
>
> 2.-I understand this example is a inner join isn't it? I take it for this line "from="accountid" to="customerid"" this sees as a Inner Join
> then how would it be a cross join?
>
> 3.- I copied this example on http://mscrmshop.blogspot.mx/2012/09/outer-joins-in-fetch-xml-queries-in.html

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="opportunity">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="customerid" />
     <attribute name="estimatedvalue_base" />
     <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="customerid" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="accountid">
      <attribute name="telephone1" />
    </link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch XML does not support a cross Join.

There is another alternative solution suggested in the below link. Please see whether that can be useful for your case.

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3ee734c-81d3-4277-b54f-c2e46bb20e0d/crm-2011-sql-cross-join-equivalent-fetchxml-in-report?forum=crmdevelopment

Comment: and support a join as <link-entity name="account" from="1" to="1" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="accountid">?????